# Rails3 + Typus: display habtm relationship as checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, checkbox, relationships, admin-interface

I'm managing my admin backend with [Typus](https://github.com/fesplugas/typus)

I want to add a field with a checkbox for each category.
I used this code:

```
Post:
  fields:
    default: name, description, user, categories
    list: name, description, user, categories
    form: name, description, user, categories
  relationships: categories
```

But the result is a textfield with a [] inside: how do I solve this?
Is there a native way or must I override the field template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the the checkbox for the fields you can use the existing template of the Typus

```
Post:
  fields:
   default: name, description, user, categories
   list: name, description, user, categories
   form: name, description, user, categories
   options:
     templates:
       categories: boolean
   relationships: categories`
```