# How to only show the subcategories for a category in Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I have the following models:

```
Category

has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories
has_many :resources

Subcategory

has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :resources
Resource

has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories
belongs_to  :category
```

In Rails_Admin when creating or editing a resource I want to show the subcategories for the chosen category.

How can I do this in rails_admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rails_admin/rLCsCy7X50M) should give you a couple of options to get you what you need. And, here is another [post](https://gist.github.com/1093488) about building custom views for the relationships in rails_admin.

## Edited

Check out this post [Rails3 + Typus: display habtm relationship as checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270512/rails3-typus-display-habtm-relationship-as-checkboxes)

Comment: Thanks Mike for the links however its not exactly what I was asking. I want to show checkboxes of subcategories depending on the categories chosen.

Comment: @chell - I've updated my answer with another possible helpful solution.